# How to share searchText between vim search and vim substitute?

Tags: search, vim, substitution

When i need to replace a string with a new string in vim.

First i would use search-mode  to check that the search pattern is correct.

```
/search pattern
```

Then use the 's' command to do substitution.

```
:%s/search pattern/new string/
```

The search pattern need to type twice. If it is too complex, it would be boring.

Is there a method to avoid this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Also (in addition to Marco Baldelli's correct answer), the *last search pattern* is stored in the special register `/`. You can insert this in the command-line via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, followed by <kbd>/</kbd>. (This also works in insert mode, and also with other registers.) It's helpful when you want to tweak your search pattern before substituting.

Comment: You're welcome! Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor.

Answer (score 10):

You can simply omit the pattern in the substitution command, e.g.

```
:%s//new string/
```

This is documented in `:help last-pattern` (emphasis mine):

> The last used pattern and offset are remembered.  They can be used to
>   repeat the search, possibly in another direction or with another
>   count.  Note that two patterns are remembered: One for 'normal' search
>   commands and one for the substitute command ":s".  **Each time an empty
>   pattern is given, the previously used pattern is used.**